# Issue referencing arrays subproperties on Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

[image]

When adding [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable), 200)] to the methods, we are getting an issue when the swagger documentation is generated. The subproperties of array/list types don't get referenced, as you can see the image below.

[image]

If we set this property not as IEnumerable/List, just as the class type, the response type properties are well generated, as example,

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember Swashbuckle does not handle inheritance very well.

We wrap enumerable responses in an object to protect from [JSON hijacking](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx).

```
[ResponseType(typeof(ResponseWrapper<IEnumerable<Model>>))]
```

And as a side effect (or workaround, if you will), Swashbuckle is happy with it and generates docs just fine.

ResponseWrapper here is

```
sealed class ResponseWrapper<T>
{
    public ResponseWrapper(T response)
    {
        Value = response;
    }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```